Evaluation of BaggingClassifier using Out-of-bag observations is an indirect evaluation of bagging classifier?
May I know is the following correct?
When evaluating a BaggingClassifier using out-of-bag (OOB) samples, the goal is indeed to assess the performance of the ensemble as a whole, rather than focusing on individual base classifiers. The OOB evaluation provides an estimate of how well the ensemble generalizes to unseen data.
Here's the distinction:
Original BaggingClassifier with Majority Voting: In the original BaggingClassifier, when making predictions, each base classifier contributes a prediction, and the final prediction for each data point is determined by majority voting. This ensemble method aims to leverage the diversity of the base classifiers to improve overall performance.
Evaluation of BaggingClassifier with OOB Samples: When evaluating the BaggingClassifier using OOB samples, each individual base classifier is evaluated independently using its corresponding OOB samples. The performance metrics obtained from these evaluations provide insight into the effectiveness of the ensemble approach, considering the collective performance of all base classifiers.
So, essentially the OOB evaluation assesses the overall quality of the ensemble, rather than directly evaluating the BaggingClassifier itself. However, since the BaggingClassifier's performance relies on the performance of its constituent base classifiers, the OOB evaluation indirectly informs us about the BaggingClassifier's performance. If the base classifiers perform well individually on OOB samples, it suggests that the ensemble is likely to perform well overall.
